# Dividing a fixed number over multiple rows by weight

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have a table that has this structure:

```
Id - Team - User - Weight
```

For example: In a team we have the goal to reach 500 calls, so I'd have to spread the 500 calls by weight over each user in the team so I get this structure returned:

```
 Id - Team - User - Weight - # Calls to be made
```

I know I can do this with a OVER(partition by) and that works perfectly, except for one little detail, there's no way to make half a call.

I'd need this distribution to be without commas.

The basic query:

```
select Id,Team,User,Weight from CallList

4   ED  PEDRO       1
5   RE  PEDRO       1
6   PO  ROOEIC      0,5
7   PO  ROOEIC01    0,5
1   AP  APSYSL      0,333333333333333
2   AP  APSYSL01    0,333333333333333
3   AP  APSYSL02    0,333333333333333
```

And this is what I would want returned

```
4   ED  PEDRO       1                    500
5   RE  PEDRO       1                    500
6   PO  ROOEIC      0,5                  250
7   PO  ROOEIC01    0,5                  250
1   AP  APSYSL      0,333333333333333    167
2   AP  APSYSL01    0,333333333333333    167
3   AP  APSYSL02    0,333333333333333    166
```

Comment: you can actually do a left join to specify the weight for each team using a temp table.

Comment: Unfortunately, your weights do not add up to "1", which makes this harder.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention that, but it's always 500 per team, so the team's total weight is always 1.

Comment: Can you show your existing quary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an arithmetic problem.  The idea is to get a "base" value for each `id` in a team.  Then calculate the excess and incrementally add the excess.

```
select t.*,
       (start_value +
        (case when row_number() over (partition by team order by id) <= excess
              then 1 else 0
         end)
        ) as calls
from (select t.*,
             floor(weight * 500) as start_value,
             500 - sum(floor(weight * 500)) over (partition by team) as excess
      from t
     ) t;
```

This adds the excess from the first row.  You seem to want it from the last row.  You can achieve that using `order by id desc` in the `row_number()`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! had to make 1 adjustment: "then case when excess=0 then 0 else 1 end else 0"

Comment: @Pulsarz . . . The logic was backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying Gordon's logic to remove the Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
  ,floor(500 * weight)    -- always <= 500
     + CASE               -- check if there's a remainder n, if yes split it across n rows
         WHEN COUNT(*)    -- get a (kind of) random row, using row_number/order you might define a specific row
              OVER (PARTITION BY Team
                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
              <= (500 - SUM(floor(500*weight)) -- remainder calculation
                        OVER (PARTITION BY Team))
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0
       END
FROM CallList
```